# Nginx isn't listening correctly on port 80

Tags: nginx, https, http

Nginx seems to only listen on HTTPS. This is the root configuration for Port 80, which isn't working (no response). I have two sub-domains configured separately,
one of which DOES receive HTTP requests (mail.example.de)

Cloud:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name cloud.example.de;
    # enforce https
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Mail:

```
server {
    listen 80 ssl;
    listen [::]:80 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.de/privkey.pem;

    server_name mail.example.de;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:480;
    }

    location /.well-known {
      root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }
}
```

Root:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name *.example.de example.de;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I thought it was kind of strange that this didn't send any responses, so I tried

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name *.example.de example.de;
return 200 'Response!';
add_header Content-Type text/plain;

}
```

Comment: `listen 80 ssl` is really weird. You should not do this unless you're 1000% sure, and you're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check for nginx service status? Its logs?

At first glance: you can not have both http and https listeners on the same port.

Remove the "Mail" snippet out of your configurations - or changes its 80 port (https usually uses 443 anyway). Restart nginx, this should fix your http sites.

Comment: The Mail snippet works, it redirects to https as it should. The other ones are not working

Comment: So I tried it anyway and it worked. Could you tell me why exactly it hadn't been working? There were no errors either which was confusing to me

Comment: @SYN insight is correct: it is impossible to use SSL in one virtual host on some port and at the same time run non-SSL virtual host on the same port. Why in the world you could want to run HTTPS on port 80 anyway?

Comment: I probably copied this from somewhere, I was a bit confused about it as well